# SQL: Copy from column to another column with replace space

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in my `DataBase` like this:-

```
ID       Name              Url         Date
11   News title test2               22-10-2014
12   News title test3               22-10-2014
13   News title test4               22-10-2014
```

Now I need to copy the value from `Name` to `Url` and replace the space to  `-`

So, The table must be like after copy :-

```
ID       Name                     Url                    Date
11   News title test2       News-title-test2           22-10-2014
12   News title test3       News-title-test2           22-10-2014
13   News title test4       News-title-test2           22-10-2014
```

Are there way to do that by `SQL` or `PHP`

Answer (score 3):

Simply update the table and use the `REPLACE()` function

```
UPDATE table
SET Url = REPLACE(Name,' ', '-')
```

Comment: Thankx but my roe is Arabic What can do ??